# Package: calling method from multiple controllers

Tags: php, laravel, package, laravel-5, helper

I'm calling a method from multiple controllers in my application.  I don't want to have duplicate code in my project, so I'm looking for a way to put the method somewhere, so I can call it from every controller.

I did some research and I stumbled upon "Helpers". (I dont' know if this is the right way to solve this. Other approaches are welcome too) I've read [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5?page=1) post and did exactly what Jeffrey Way  said in his post, but I still get following error:

> Call to undefined function initFb()

I've tried `composer dump-autoload`.

So this is my `helpers.php`:

```
<?php

if (! function_exists('initFb'))
{
    function initFb()
    {
        $fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
            'app_id' => getenv('FACEBOOK_APP_ID'),
            'app_secret' => getenv('FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'),
            'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
        ]);

        return $fb;
    }
}
```

My composer.json of my package:

```
"files": [
           "src/helpers.php"
       ]
```

**Important**

This is for a package I'm developing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To register your own `helpers.php` file, add these lines into Laravel's `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
        ...
        "files": [
            "app/some_path/helpers.php"
        ]
```

For classes use `psr-4` section:

```
"psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "YourName\\PackageNamespace\\": "packages/yourname/package-name/src"
        },
```

Then run `composer dumpauto` (if doesn't help, try `composer dumpauto -o`).

Also, try with some simple helper to test if it works , do something like this:

```
if (! function_exists('helpersTest'))
{
    function helpersTest()
    {
        return 'It works!';
    }
}
```

If you're trying to use these helpers after installing your package with `composer` (from `Packagist`), you should add these lines to package's `composer.json` file.

Comment: DId you add these lines to Laravel's `composer.json`?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. You're saying that it should be in the main app's composer.json?

Comment: Yep. Try to put these lines into app's `composer.json`

Comment: Oh, what's the logic behind that? I was thinking this shouldn't be anything the users of my package should have to do so I put it in the composer.json? Is there a way that the users of the package should not have to do it theirselves?

Comment: When user will download your package with composer, package's `composer.json` will be used. So, you need to add these lines there too and test it when you upload your package to Packagist. Now, while you developing your package, you need to use app's `composer.json`

Comment: Oh, so everything that is in my package's `composer.json` file will be in the main composer.json file after installation? But for testing purposes I should add it manually?

Comment: No. When you'll install your package with `composer.json`, it will be downloaded to `vendor` directory and will have it's own `composer.json` (copy of the package's one). And yes, now you should add it manually to app's `composer.json`

Comment: I still hit an error though: `require failed to open stream. no such file (autoload_real.php)`

Comment: Doublecheck paths. Also, try to delete autoload files manually and then run `composer dumpauto` to build them.

Comment: Thanks man. Been searching on this the whole time. Appreciate you spending your time to answer me.

Comment: Another small question: I had kind of the same issue with providers in my package. The package (Socialite in this case) was installed, but the provider & aliases weren't known by the package (undefined class Socialite). Is this the same deal? So I also have to register the provider and the aliases manually to work? And later it will go automatically (when people install it via composer)

Comment: Glad it helped. ) I didn't use Socialite, so maybe I misunderstood you. But any user should always add providers and aliases manually in `config/app`. Also, sometimes you need to run `composer dumpauto` and with `-o` to make it work.